# How can I handle Doctrine errors?

Tags: symfony

I am using Doctrine's `dbal` service in my Symfony2 app.

I query a non-existent table, which throws an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'log.requests_20130311' doesn't exist.

Symfony2 catches this before I can, even in a `try-catch` block. I don't want this to kill my application. How can I handle it?

Comment: Just subscribe to the `kernel.exception` event and catch it? (I haven't done this before, that's why I posted a comment)

Comment: @Wouter J you're right the kernel exception listener catch all the exceptions (but you can configure it to catch just some exception) and if you want to use a try catch be sure to write your catch this way : `catch (\Exception $e)` because if you don't add the `\ ` symfony will search the Exception in your controller

Comment: I just needed the \. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Per @Coussinsky's comment, you need to have a `\` in front of your exception:

```
try {
    $result_set = $this->connection->query($sql);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Doctrines DBAL layer is a wrapper around PDO, so you should be able to do:

```
try {
    // Query your non-existent table
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    // Deal with it without killing your app
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html

Comment: old topic but shouldn't we catch a more generic exception in case the driver changes to ODM or anything else?